# Смогу ли я подключить ССД PCI Express 3.0 x4 в слот PCI Express 4.0 x4?

Tags: железо, ssd

Смогу ли я подключить `ССД PCI Express 3.0 x4` в слот `PCI Express 4.0 x4` и будет ли работать стабильно?

Comment: Подключить можно, работать будет стабильно. Просто скорость будет ограничена значением интерфейса 3.0.

Comment: Спасибо, именно это я и хотел узнать

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что не в физический PCIe тыкать собираетесь а в логический, который физически M2 NVME, а там важнее угадать с ключами(прорезями в разъеме).